# C - 2D array detects too many neighbours from input

Tags: c, multidimensional-array, conways-game-of-life

**2D array neighbour problem**

Hello!

I've been working on this code for a Conway's game of life program and I'm running into a problem with the neighbour detecting function within my program. The input takes a matrix from the user of alive and dead cells, then parses it to detect neighbours using the function below, I understand I require some kind of shadow border to remove the excess neighbour problem but cannot figure out how to implement this.

**Example of function for detecting neighbours:**

```
int neighbourCount(int row, int column, char grid[row][column]){
    int count = 0;

    if(grid[row-1][column-1] == 'X') {
        count++;
    }
    if(grid[row-1][column] == 'X') {
        count++;
    }
    if(grid[row-1][column+1] == 'X') {
        count++;
    }
    if(grid[row][column-1] == 'X') {
        count++;
    }
    if(grid[row][column+1] == 'X') {
        count++;
    }
    if(grid[row+1][column-1] == 'X') {
        count++;
    }
    if(grid[row+1][column] == 'X') {
        count++;
    }
    if(grid[row+1][column+1] == 'X') {
        count++;
    }

    return count;
}
```

**Input for 2d array and array declaration**

```
char grid[row][column];

int i, j;
for(i=0; i<row; i++) {
    for(j=0;j<column;j++) {
        scanf(" %c", &grid[i][j]);
    }
}
```

**Example input:**

XXX

XXX

XXX

**Neighbour amount for first alive cell in 2d array**

5

Any feedback or additional parts of the code can be provided and I understand the code isn't the best it could be as I am fairly new to C, this problem has got me scratching my head and is disrupting the rest of my program. Any help would be much appreciated! Thank you for any future feedback/answers.

Comment: Your function itself is hampered, it is using VLAs, which won't work. Ex: say you have a 5x5 map and you want to check cell 2,2. Your function treats the array passed as if its `char grid[2][2]`. That isn't correct. Your grid should be fixed independent of the index being checked.

Comment: You also are not checking if you are accessing `grid` out of bounds, for example when the row,col combination is on an edge.

Comment: The shadow border thing is to add extra unused elements around the matrix, so the +1 and -1 elements always exist (but are empty). You would then start `row` and `col` at 1 and not use the 0 elements. Similar for the other end of rows and columns.

Comment: Don't lose sight of my first comment. It's important. Whatever your actual play field size. it should be known by the function *in addition* to the actual cell coordinates being inspected. That requires two more arguments, though technically you only need `row`, `col`, `cols`, and `grid[][cols]`. If you're going to do bounds checking (and you should), may as well do `row`, `col`, `rows`, `cols`, and `grid[rows][cols]`.

Comment: @WhozCraig Thanks, I'm looking into your comment. You've been a great help!